# Google Cloud Message has broadcast api in server?

Tags: server, cloud, google-cloud-messaging, message

I want to know if gcm(Google Cloud Message) has broadcast api in server now. I want to push notification without register_ids.I am not sure there is a broadcast api in server. Does someone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCM 3 supports topic messaging: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

Comment: It seems that the api needs register_ids.

Comment: It needs a registration token for subscribing from the device, not for sending from the backend. That'a broadcast.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But It has different api. I write the sdk for myself from this page:  https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/notifications-d7df385b0ff4

Comment: Do you know how long the notification_key is?

Comment: The page you mention is incomplete and does not mention topic publishing available on latest GCM.

Comment: So  is it the old api? And I have tried it, it is ok.And the new api publishing available does not mention how to add registration_id

Comment: They do mention it. Please, check "Receiving topic messages on an Android client app" on the topic messaging page reference in the answer.

Comment: Oh, yes, I found it.The registration_token must be subscribe from the device but not in server.

Comment: The fact that you have message_id means success.

Comment: Is there any way to know how many devices receive the message successfully?

Comment: No, this is not possible.